# Bypassing wp_signon with a cookie that I have

Tags: single-sign-on

I'm trying to build a simple way to give access to users that I want under my account. As I see, WordPress stores two sessions ID: `wordpress_logged_in_%` and `wordpress_`. I was wondering, is there no way to force `wp_signon` or a core function to bypass the need for an user / password and use a cookie instead?

Answer (score 1):

Don't need no cookies. WordPress automatically bypasses it for you if you pass an user (the one you need to login) object, fire this function on `init` (I think):

```
$user_to_login = get_user_by( 'id', 1 );

// Check if user exists
if( $user_to_login ) {
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_to_login->ID, False );

    /**
     * Fire up the login process.
     */
    do_action('wp_login', $user_to_login->name, $user_to_login );
}
```

This is extremely rudimentary. No checks at all, nada. You must employ heavy checks as to how people use this functionality.

You'll have to solve issues such as: caching issues (usually by setting the right `header`, redirection, validity, etc.) but this works.

Comment: Be sure to mark this answer as the correct one for your question :)